# How to add a lowess (or lm) line to an existing facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's the situation, I have data with three groups (say, A, B, and C). I want to plot the relationship between X and Y, with the groups in different panels. Easy peasy:

```
set.seed(111)
groups = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1500, replace=T)
x=rnorm(1500); y = rnorm(1500, 0, sqrt(1-.25^2))
y = model.matrix(y~x*groups + I(x^2)) %*% c(0, .5, 1, 2, -.2, .2, .5) + rnorm(1500, 0, sqrt(1-.25^2))
d = data.frame(x=x, y=y, groups=groups)
b = ggplot(data=d, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() + 
    facet_wrap(~groups) +
    theme_bw()
b
```

[image]

The problem is that it's hard to visually compare the prediction line across the panels. (In this simple example, it's not hard, but it is hard for the application I have). What I thought would be a good idea is to overlay in the B/C panels the lowess line from panel A (maybe as a red line, for example). My first thought was to create a new geom_smooth for a subsetted dataset containing only the information from panel A and plotting that in the panels, but I have no idea how to modify existing panels after they've already been plotted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *very* easy, but you can use `ggplot_build()` to extract the computed information from a smooth:

```
g0 <- ggplot(data=subset(d,groups=="A"), aes(x,y))+geom_smooth()
d_smooth <- ggplot_build(g0)$data[[1]]
## add line to existing plot   
b + geom_line(data=d_smooth,colour="red")
```

[image]